# opencv_core.inRange() not allowing opencv_core.Scalar as input type

Tags: python, opencv

```
frame=cv2.imread('lena.jpg')
    hsv=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    l_b=np.array([110,50,50])
    u_b=np.array([130,255,255])

    mask=cv2.inRange(hsv,l_b,u_b)
    cv2.imshow('frame',mask)
```

> **Error-** OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:1758:
>   error: (-209:Sizes of input arguments do not match) The lower boundary
>   is neither an array of the same size and same type as src, nor a
>   scalar in function 'cv::inRange'

I am programming in python in opencv and this error comes up. Is there any way I can avoid this and get the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of converting the frame into grayscale, you have to convert it to HSV.

```
#Change this line
hsv=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
```

Comment: @SenudaJayalath If an answer has worked for you, try to upvote the answer and mark it as the answer to your post, so if others had the same problem be sure to try the answer given to you.